# Prove that $\int_a^{a+T}f(x)dx$ is independent of $a$ if $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $T$

Tags: integration

> Prove that $\int_a^{a+T}f(x)dx$ is independent of $a$ if $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $T$

I indeed  don't how to treat to this problem.

Comment: What is $T$? The period?

Comment: Hint: Show that $I = \int_0^k f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ regardless of the value of $a$. Splitting the integral into two integrals (the split being determined by the value of $a$) or a change of variables (the specific change also being determined by the value of $a$) might be needed.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: D o you think we can take $I$ as an function of $a$?

Comment: @BabakSorouh Yes, of course, as Grapth's answer shows, that is a very easy way of solving the problem. The way suggested in my hint is developed in more detail in the answer by Didier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $nT$ denote the unique multiple of $T$ in $[a,a+T)$. Then $I=J+K$ where 
$$
J=\int_a^{nT}f(x)\mathrm dx,\qquad K=\int_{nT}^{a+T}f(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
The change of variables $x=t-T+nT$ in $J$ yields 
$$
J=\int_{a-nT+T}^Tf(t)\mathrm dt.
$$
The change of variables $x=s+nT$ in $K$ yields 
$$
K=\int_0^{a-nT+T}f(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
Thus $I=\displaystyle\int_0^Tf(u)\mathrm du$ is independent of $a$.

Answer (score 6):

So, clearly, $I$ is a function of $a$.  Let us find $I'(a)$.  Since $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a, a + k]$, the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applies to give
$$I'(a) = f(a + T) - f(a).$$
Since $f$ is periodic of period $T$, $f(a + T) = f(a)$, so $I'(a) = 0$.  Therefore, $I(a)$ is the constant function.  In other words, as $a$ changes, $I(a)$ does not, so $I$ does not depend on $a$.

Comment: I asked it above to do what you did here. Glad you did it perfect. +1